Rxjs async queue pause and resume problem
My situation is: websocket will keep sending audio binary, I use concatMap play these binary in a async queue.
const audio = new Audio()
subject.pipe(
    concatMap(v => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            audio.url = URL.createObjectURL(v)
            
            audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
                resolve(v)
            })
            audio.play()
        })
    })
).subscribe()

It works fine.
And there will be local recording interrupt audio playing,
when recording stops, async play will resume.
(pause randomly, resume randomly)
If I use takeUntil() it can't resume again.
So in this async queue, I tried use outside variables in concatMap write some ugly code to skip playing, but how to interrupt/resume gracefully?
Any thoughts? Just ignore all the binary while interrupting, rewrite the async queue is fine.

I guess one other way to handle this is - use BehaviorSubject to manage the playback state and switchMap to handle the audio stream.
Sample Usage
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const audio = new Audio();
const playbackState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true); // true means play, false means pause
const subject = new Subject<Blob>();

subject.pipe(
    switchMap(v => playbackState.pipe(
        switchMap(play => play ? playAudio(v) : [])
    ))
).subscribe();

function playAudio(blob: Blob): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        audio.addEventListener('ended', () => resolve(), { once: true });
        audio.play();
    });
}

Use the playbackState subject to control when to play or pause the audio.
function pausePlayback() {
    playbackState.next(false);
    audio.pause();
}

function resumePlayback() {
    playbackState.next(true);
    audio.play();
}

Actual Implementation
startRecordingButton.addEventListener('click', pausePlayback);
stopRecordingButton.addEventListener('click', resumePlayback);

Here BehaviorSubject allows you to control the playback state, and switchMap ensures that the audio stream is managed correctly based on the playback state.
------------------------ EDIT USING CONCAT MAP -------------------
I understand that you want to preserve the order (or) do things sequentially. Then you can try something like this:
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject, from, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, filter, mergeMap, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AudioQueue {
  private audioQueue$ = new Subject<Blob>();
  private playbackState$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  private audio = new Audio();

  constructor() {
    this.setupAudioQueue();
  }

  private setupAudioQueue() {
    this.audioQueue$.pipe(
      concatMap(blob => this.playWithPauseResume(blob))
    ).subscribe();
  }

  private playWithPauseResume(blob: Blob): Observable<void> {
    return new Observable<void>(observer => {
      const playAudio = () => {
        this.audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        this.audio.play();
        this.audio.onended = () => {
          observer.next();
          observer.complete();
        };
      };

      const subscription = this.playbackState$.pipe(
        filter(play => play),
        take(1)
      ).subscribe(() => {
        playAudio();
      });

      return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.audio.pause();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.audio.src);
      };
    });
  }

  public addToQueue(blob: Blob) {
    this.audioQueue$.next(blob);
  }

  public pausePlayback() {
    this.playbackState$.next(false);
    this.audio.pause();
  }

  public resumePlayback() {
    this.playbackState$.next(true);
  }
}

THIS IS HOW YOU CAN USE IT
// Usage example
const queue = new AudioQueue();

// Simulating incoming audio blobs
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).pipe(
  concatMap(v => timer(1000).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log(`Processing ${v}`)),
    mergeMap(() => {
      // Simulating blob creation
      const blob = new Blob([`Audio chunk ${v}`], { type: 'audio/wav' });
      queue.addToQueue(blob);
      return [];
    })
  ))
).subscribe();

// Simulating pause after 3 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Pausing playback');
  queue.pausePlayback();
}, 3000);

// Simulating resume after 6 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Resuming playback');
  queue.resumePlayback();
}, 6000);


Thank you for this idea, didn't use BehaviorSubject before, I'll try this solution

Just tried it, but switchMap will ignore the async sequence
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).pipe(
      switchMap((v) => {
        console.log(v)
        return this.playbackState.pipe(
          switchMap(play => {
            return play ? new Promise(resolve => {
              timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
                resolve(v)
              })
            }) : []
          })
        )
      })
    );

It will print all the value in one time.
